# Spring WebFlux (Flux): how to publish dynamically

Tags: spring-webflux

I am new to Reactive programming and Spring WebFlux. I want to make my App 1 publish Server Sent event through Flux and my App 2 listen on it continuously.

I want Flux publish on-demand (e.g. when something happens). All the example I found is to use Flux.interval to periodically publish event, and there seems no way to append/modify the content in Flux once it is created.

How can I achieve my goal? Or I am totally wrong conceptually.

Comment: Similar question is about publishing sse events "from another method". see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72983103/11152683 There are Sinks as solution with simmilar example like here.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## Publish "dynamically" using `FluxProcessor` and `FluxSink`

One of the techniques to supply data manually to the `Flux` is using `FluxProcessor#sink` method as in the following example

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    final FluxProcessor processor;
    final FluxSink sink;
    final AtomicLong counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    }

    public DemoApplication() {
        this.processor = DirectProcessor.create().serialize();
        this.sink = processor.sink();
        this.counter = new AtomicLong();
    }

    @GetMapping("/send")
    public void test() {
        sink.next("Hello World #" + counter.getAndIncrement());
    }

    @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent> sse() {
        return processor.map(e -> ServerSentEvent.builder(e).build());
    }
}
```

Here, I created `DirectProcessor` in order to support multiple subscribers, that will listen to the data stream. Also, I provided additional `FluxProcessor#serialize` which provide safe support for multiproducer (invocation from different threads without violation of Reactive Streams spec rules, especially [rule 1.3](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.2/README.md#1.3)). Finally, by calling "http://localhost:8080/send" we will see the message `Hello World #1` (of course, only in case if you connected to the "http://localhost:8080" previously)

### Update For Reactor 3.4

With Reactor 3.4 you have a new API called `reactor.core.publisher.Sinks`. `Sinks` API offers a fluent builder for manual data-sending which lets you specify things like the number of elements in the stream and backpressure behavior, number of supported subscribers, and replay capabilities:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    final Sinks.Many sink;
    final AtomicLong counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    }

    public DemoApplication() {
        this.sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
        this.counter = new AtomicLong();
    }

    @GetMapping("/send")
    public void test() {
        EmitResult result = sink.tryEmitNext("Hello World #" + counter.getAndIncrement());

        if (result.isFailure()) {
          // do something here, since emission failed
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent> sse() {
        return sink.asFlux().map(e -> ServerSentEvent.builder(e).build());
    }
}
```

Note, message sending via `Sinks` API introduces a new concept of `emission` and its result. The reason for such API is the fact that the Reactor extends Reactive-Streams and has to follow the backpressure control. That said if you `emit` more signals than was requested, and the underlying implementation does not support buffering, your message will not be delivered. Therefore, the result of `tryEmitNext` returns the `EmitResult` which indicates if the message was sent or not.

Also, note, that by default `Sinsk` API gives a serialized version of `Sink`, which means you don't have to care about concurrency. However, if you know in advance that the emission of the message is serial, you may build a `Sinks.unsafe()` version which does not serialize given messages

Comment: I test this and it works fine! To subscribe to the event, access "http://localhost:8080". Thanks!

Comment: How can I do this for a Mono?

Comment: Very interesting. Would you happen to remember where you learned about these things? Never seen this sort of implementation.

Comment: Also you would like to parameterize your `FluxProcessor<IN, OUT>` like so: `this.processor = DirectProcessor.<T>create().serialize()` where T is your type of event

Comment: think it's better to use processor.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()) before map() to split thread for "send" and "sse"

Comment: We will have one publisher available for all the subscriber with this implementation. How to achieve it for one subscriber with one publisher only ?

Comment: How to change this solution to use `Sinks` in thread safe (in sense of reactive streams) way as processors are getting deprecated?

Comment: I thought this was not possible with SSE, then what is the difference between SSE and Websockets?

Answer (score 5):

**Just another idea, using EmitterProcessor as a gateway to flux**

```java
    import reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor;
    import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

    public class MyEmitterProcessor {
        EmitterProcessor<String> emitterProcessor;

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            MyEmitterProcessor myEmitterProcessor = new MyEmitterProcessor();
            Flux<String> publisher = myEmitterProcessor.getPublisher();
            myEmitterProcessor.onNext("A");
            myEmitterProcessor.onNext("B");
            myEmitterProcessor.onNext("C");
            myEmitterProcessor.complete();

            publisher.subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));

        }

        public Flux<String> getPublisher() {
            emitterProcessor = EmitterProcessor.create();
            return emitterProcessor.map(x -> "consume: " + x);
        } 

        public  void onNext(String nextString) {
            emitterProcessor.onNext(nextString);
        }

        public  void complete() {
            emitterProcessor.onComplete();
        }
    }
```

More info, [see here from Reactor doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processors). There is a recommendation from the document itself that "Most of the time, you should try to avoid using a Processor. They are harder to use correctly and prone to some corner cases." BUT I don't know which kind of corner case.

Comment: In the mean time class `EmitterProcessor` has been marked as deprecated and will be removed in version 3.5. As an alternative solution the use of `Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer()` is recommended (as proposed in the first answer to this question).

Comment: Yes thanks @Dominik the Sinks is working for me.