# Spring Webflex: Push Server Sent Event to Specific Users

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I have been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370463/spring-webflux-flux-how-to-publish-dynamically) for reference. I am developing a spring-boot app which will have authenticated users. Once logged in, a user will subscribe to an event by visiting a specific URL.

This spring-boot app will also either support MQTT (or maybe just HTTP requests) in which information for a specific user will be sent. I would like to then display this sent information to the user using web flux/SSE if the user has subscribed.

Many users can be logged in at any given time, and they will have all subscribed to the updates. How do I manage all the different sinks for each logged in user?

I believe it's possible to get the current user when they visit the authenticated URL, but what's a method of storing all of the sinks for each logged in user?

I appreciate it.

Comment: You can use one sink, and just subscribe to it multiple times for each user.

Comment: When I receive data for a user, it is only intended for a user. When I would call sink.next to push the data, how could I specify which user is getting it? Many users will be subscribed.

Comment: You can use a filter, put your conditions in that

Comment: I'm trying to follow. I understand I can use the Java 8 filter, but what would I be filtering? The MQTT or HTTP data I get will be to a specific topic/id, so I can figure out which user it belong to. But, what parameter can I add to the filter so I know the message is going to the correct user?

Answer (score 3):

You already got the answer in the comment section.

Lets assume that this is the message format you would be publishing.

```
public class Message {

    private int intendedUserId;
    private String message;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Just have 1 processor and sink from the processor.

```
 FluxProcessor<Message> processor;
 FluxSink<Message> sink;
```

Push all the messages via the sink.

```
sink.next(msg);
```

Your controller would be more or less like this. Here I assume you have some method to get the user id `authtoken.getUserId()`. Here the filter is part of the Flux.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/msg", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Message> getMessages(){
    return processer
                .filter(msg -> msg.getIntendedUserId() == authtoken.getUserId());
}
```