# WebFlux and Reactor 3.4.0 - Deprecated FluxProcessors - How to subscribe with a sink?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

With Reactor 3.4.0 the different FluxProcessors like "DirectProcessor" is getting deprecated. I  used such processor as subscribers, see example below.

Now I am wondering how I have to migrate my code to make use of the recommended `Sinks.many()` approach? Any ideas?

Old Code:

```
DirectProcessor<String> output = DirectProcessor.create();
output.subscribe(msg -> System.out.println(msg));

WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
client.execute(uri, session -> 
    // send message
    session.send(Mono.just(session.textMessage(command)))
        .thenMany(session.receive()
        .map(message -> message.getPayloadAsText())
        .subscribeWith(output))
    .then()).block();
```

According the [JavaDoc of the deprecated DirectProcessor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/DirectProcessor.html) I should make use of `Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort()`. But I am wondering how to use this in my WebSocketClient?

Migrated Code:

```
Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();        
Flux<String> flux = sink.asFlux();
flux.subscribe(msg -> System.out.println(msg));

WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
client.execute(uri, session -> 
    // send message
    session.send(Mono.just(session.textMessage(command)))
        .thenMany(session.receive()
        .map(message -> message.getPayloadAsText())
        .subscribe ...   // <-- how to do this with a Sink ??
    .then()).block();
```

Thank you for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: If anybody is still searching for this, update is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51377484/3271165