# How to repeat Mono while not empty

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method which returns like this!

```
Mono<Integer> getNumberFromSomewhere();
```

I need to keep calling this until it has no more items to emit. That is I need to make this as `Flux<Integer>`.

One option is to add `repeat`. the point is - I want to stop when the above method emits the first empty signal.

Is there any way to do this? I am looking for a clean way.

Comment: How do you know it has no more items to emit?

Comment: Mono would be emitting empty

Comment: I would look at something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370463/spring-webflux-flux-how-to-publish-dynamically

Comment: another possibility is `expand`: `Flux<Integer> expanded = monoWithUnderlyingState.expand(i -> monoWithUnderlyingState);`

Comment: @SimonBaslé this is perfect. Please add this an answer - so i could accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A built-in operator that does that (although it is intended for "deeper" nesting) is `expand`.

`expand` naturally stops expansion when the returned `Publisher` completes empty.

You could apply it to your use-case like this:

```
//this changes each time one subscribes to it
Mono<Integer> monoWithUnderlyingState;

Flux<Integer> repeated = monoWithUnderlyingState
    .expand(i -> monoWithUnderlyingState);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a built-in operator which would do the job straightaway. However, it can be done using a wrapper class and a mix of operators:

```java
Flux<Integer> repeatUntilEmpty() {
    return getNumberFromSomewhere()
        .map(ResultWrapper::new)
        .defaultIfEmpty(ResultWrapper.EMPTY)
        .repeat()
        .takeWhile(ResultWrapper::isNotEmpty)
}

// helper class, not necessarily needs to be Java record
record ResultWrapper(Integer value) {
    public static final ResultWrapper EMPTY = new ResultWrapper(null);

    public boolean isNotEmpty() {
        return value != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is to use the singleOptional() method, then repeat() and takeUntil(Optional::isEmpty).

EG: queue.poll().singleOptional().repeat().takeUntil(Optional::isEmpty).map(Optional::get)